# Calculation of The Total value is Wrong

Tags: c#, datagridview, calculation

I have the code, everything's fine until I put the **number bigger than** 3000, the **result** will be **negative number**, please help.

I dont know why it's happened, I have already debug it, or it about I declare it by int?

The total value I mention is the  **int total= quantity * cost;**

And by the way, is there anyway to **prevent** user type **anything** else except **numberic** to **Quantity column?**

```
 private void G2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int quantity, cost;
            if (int.TryParse(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && int.TryParse(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Cost2"].Value.ToString(), out cost))
            {
                int total= quantity * cost;
                G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = total.ToString();
            }

            int quan, mini;

            quan = Convert.ToInt32(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value);
            mini = Convert.ToInt32(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MinimumOrder2"].Value);

            if (quan < mini)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("QUANTITY must be GREATER or EQUAL to MINIMUM ORDER", "STOP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value = "";
                G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = "";
                return;

            }
            else
            {
                //Sum the Total Column to TOTAL VALUES text box
                decimal TotalValue = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < G2.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (G2.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TotalValue += Convert.ToDecimal(G2.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);
                    }
                }

                totalvalue.Text = TotalValue.ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Only Number");
            return;
        }

    }
```

[Example input by user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzODd.png)

Comment: Could you also show the code for your datagrid?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid everything work fine except this.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the debugger to check what happen in this code? This seems something connected to your actual data.

Comment: @Steve I just edited for you easy to understand

Comment: @Steve like i said i already debugged

Comment: @Serenade, Your data is coming from your datagrid, that is your source. If you do not post that I doubt we can help you.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid the quantity is inputed by user, not in data source

Comment: @Serenade, With 'source' I did not mean the property 'DataSource' but the source of your problem, the root. The user puts his data into a datagrid right? Show us the code for the datagrid so we can see if there is anything that may cause this behaviour.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid this is THE ROOT, the user input then  the code is activated, input from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

One issue is the "total loop".  I think the `return` should be a `continue`.

```
if (G2.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value == DBNull.Value)
{
    continue;
}
```

Another issue is that the calculated `total` for the clicked on row is calculated as an `int` not a `decimial`.  Change code to:

```
int quantity;
decimal cost;
if(int.TryParse(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && 
   decimal.TryParse(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Cost2"].Value.ToString(), out cost))
        {
            int total= quantity * cost;
            G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = total.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: i used this to prevent the error Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. So if it null, return, let users finish theirs input

Comment: this line is wrong **int total= quantity * cost; **

Comment: I cannot type int in total because cost in decimal

Comment: Sorry, my "copy and paste" error. It should be `decimal total = quantity * cost;`

Answer (score 0):

One another Issue may be allowing the user to enter the values in Total. And **Below is the code to allow only numbers in Quantity Field**

```
private void G2_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        String sCellName = G2.Columns[G2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name.ToUpper();
        if (sCellName == "QUANTITY") //----change with yours
        {

            e.Control.KeyPress +=  new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);


        }
    }

    private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.'
            && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I still can type "hhhh" "aaaa" to the cell,
I already add EdittingControlShowing to event datagridview
about the Control_Keypress, Where do I add this ?

Comment: Can you please verify that the Quantity Field name is same as provided..?

Comment: `String sCellName = G2.Columns[G2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name.ToUpper();
            if (sCellName == "Quantity") //----change with yours
            {

                e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);


            }`
yes the Quantity field name is Quantity

Comment: add the code of Control_KeyPress  just below the methods  in the form

Comment: you mean add in the event of datagridview G2? the key press event?

Comment: just provide the same way as i provided the code under the Editing Control showing method

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] Dont use int anymore, change it to decimal

```
private void G2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        decimal quantity, cost;
        if (decimal .TryParse(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && decimal .TryParse(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Cost2"].Value.ToString(), out cost))
        {
            decimal total= quantity * cost;
            G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = total.ToString();
        }

        int quan, mini;

        quan = Convert.ToInt32(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value);
        mini = Convert.ToInt32(G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["MinimumOrder2"].Value);

        if (quan < mini)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("QUANTITY must be GREATER or EQUAL to MINIMUM ORDER", "STOP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value = "";
            G2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = "";
            return;

        }
        else
        {
            //Sum the Total Column to TOTAL VALUES text box
            decimal TotalValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < G2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (G2.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    TotalValue += Convert.ToDecimal(G2.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);
                }
            }

            totalvalue.Text = TotalValue.ToString();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Only Number");
        return;
    }

}
```